# Responsive CSS float table when resizing for mobile

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a page with a simple 2 column CSS table inside a general container div, like so:

```
#container:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
#col_1 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
#col_2 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

It works correctly on computers but on mobile the two columns overlap/overlay and I would like col2 to go underneath col1. In other words float ONLY if there is room for both, otherwise become two rows.
How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: add your html please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't have your HTML code, I can only do a mock-up by myself. Add media query for breakpoint for the mobile device.

```css
html,
body,
#container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#col_1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background: orange;
}

#col_2 {
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 20px); /* The 20px is the padding-right of the col_1 */
  height: 100px;
  background: lime;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  #col_1 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #col_2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="col_1"></div>
  <div id="col_2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @yinsweet - that's exactly what I was looking for... I don't think I need to specify height, do I?

Comment: @marcnyc yes. you dont have to specify height if you have something in the div.